# Doxygen 1.8.7 / GraphViz 2.38 compatabilty issue

Tags: windows, doxygen, graphviz

I recently upgraded from Doxygen 1.8.4 and GraphViz 2.36 where I had no problems generating graphs to Doxygen 1.8.7 and GraphViz 2.38 and cannot now get graphs.

During the build I get large numbers of errors of the form

> error: Problems running dot: exit code=-1, command='dot' arguements="myfile.dot" -Tpng -O "myfile.png"

I have downgraded to GraphViz 2.36 and the problem has disappeared.
NOTE - I have tried to run 2.36 with DOT_PATH empty and GraphViz added to path but this doesn't work either.

Only working solution at present is 2.36 with DOT_PATH defined.

Can you please check the compatibily issue and advise.

Comment: I currently cannot reach the graphviz site, but from dot -V I get: dot - graphviz version 2.30.1 (20130214.1330); Can you post this date information as well or try to upgrade?

Comment: My bad typing.  Version is actually 2.38 so is actually a later version.  The graphviz site is available (just very slow at present)

Comment: I tried with version 2.38 and didn't see a problem. Can you try with -d extcmd and also with DOT_PATH set to the right directory. Which OS are you using? I tested on windows.

Comment: I noticed in the `GraphViz\bin` directory, the application is `dot.exe`.  In the `c:\Program Files\dotnet` directory, I copied `dotnet.exe` to `dot.exe`.  I don't get any Doxygen errors about not finding the DOT tool, but I don't get any drawings in the HTML output either. :-(

Answer (score 16):

Another solution, that does not require to edit your $path is to set the DOT_PATH variable at the configuration file, to wherever you install the dot library (default path is `Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38/bin`).
You can do this with 2 ways:

- With the Doxywizard tool.

  - At the `expert` tab, go to the `dot` at the topics and set the `DOT_PATH` (see the [screenshot of doxywizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6Qii.png))
- Editing manually the Doxygene config file, so your doxygene **configFile** must have a line like this:

  > DOT_PATH               = "../Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38/bin"

Comment: Setting DOT_PATH variable in DoxyWizard solved the errors for me! Thanks a bunch. Also just to let anyone dealing with the issue, I already had DoxyWizard Configuration set for DOT in CodeBlocks, along with DOT bin path set in my System Path Environment Variables. But that kept on giving me the errors.

Answer (score 4):

I had exactly the same problem using Doxygen 1.8.6 and dot 2.38 (20140413.2041). Only a slight version difference compared to OP but the same error messages - and no graphs. `dot` was (and is still) set in the PATH variable but this was not enough.

It was solved though after I explicitly set `DOT_PATH` to the appropriate directory which is "C:/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38/bin" in my case.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem using Doxygen 1.8.10 and dot 2.38 with Windows 7 and `DOT_PATH` empty. At the end it was "only" a problem with the command line path: The dot utility was not found within the environment, where doxygen was run. One needs to make sure, that the dot installation directory is listed within the `PATH` environment variable. A convenient way to check is to call the command `dot.exe -V` right before calling doxygen. Then check the command line output for the dot version message.

Unfortunately the dot installation directory usually changes with each release of the GraphViz utility, since it contains a version reference (although it is not possible to have two versions of GraphViz installed in parallel). Under windows you need to manually update the global `PATH` setting and **reboot** (!) to make sure, that the setting is updated in all running environments as well.

Answer (score 2):

In my case i got this "error: Problems running dot: exit code=1.." solved only after i run

```
dot -c
```

which is meant to configure dot plugins (needs write privileges)

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this problem. I tried lots of methods mentioned in the net, but failed.
Finally, I have downgraded to GraphViz 2.38 and the problem has disappeared. Now my doxygen version is 1.8 and my graphviz version is 2.38.

Comment: Which version of doxygen? 1.8 is not a version, it has one more number lie 1.8.20 (which is the current version).