# doxygen not generating image files for dot

Tags: doxygen, doxygen-wizard

I am trying to use doxygen to scan a C# codebase and generating class diagrams/call graphs etc. using dot. I see dot files getting genarated but no images are generated. I have tried different image formats png and jpg with no change. As a result the image links are broken when I browse the classes from html. Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: This seems to work with 1.8.11 but not 1.8.13

Comment: Did you try to set the DOT_PATH ? Do you get an error message? Try to run doxygen -d extcmd Doxyfile to see which commands are used.

Answer (score 2):

The png images are generated if you install [GraphViz](https://www.graphviz.org/download/) and the program is linked with the `DOT_PATH` configuration in the Doxywizard tool like here:

> DOT_PATH               = "../Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38/bin"

I think this answers your question:
[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41762379/12756067)

Comment: This is also what was suggested in a comment but OP never responded. Also using relative paths as you did is in this case not a good idea

Comment: I can’t provide an absolute path because it depends on where you installed GraphViz.

Comment: For me my answer solved the exact problem Eqbal had, so I thought I will share it. If someone has further problems I can try to help. :)